# Can Not able to install python OpenCv on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, python-3, opencv, computer-vision

[image]

I have been trying to run my 4WD Smart drive car with raspberry 3. I am using python 3 to implement algorithms and computer vision object detection. I also have a problem with Cheese camera on the pi.

I have install this:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev -y && sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev -y && sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev -y && sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev -y && sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 -y && sudo apt-get install libqt4-test -y

 pip3 install opencv-python

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -c "import cv2"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -c "import numpy"

$ cd
$ git clone https://github.com/dctian/DeepPiCar.git

cd DeepPiCar/driver/code

 python3 opencv_test.py
```

To do this I have used the following code: see attachments

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Add the text of commands instead of picture.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot read the text on the pictures but I suppose from your title that you just want to install **OpenCV**. We have seen many problems here on this site trying to install OpenCV with pip. **OpenCV** is part of the default Raspbian repository so you can just install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

Maybe you will also need `python3-opencv-apps`.

This installation is tested and should fit best to your operating system without errors.